# How do I get the ID of the user, that lastly modified a post by passing the post ID

Tags: wordpress, loops, post, author

in Wordpress I created a post overview page. Each post in this overview page should show the avatar of the user, that lastly modified the related post. How can I get the ID of the author of a post, that lastly modified it, outside of the loop?

I found the `get_the_modified_author()` function, but it seems like it doesn't take any post ID that you could pass so in the end it only works inside the post loop.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_modified_author/

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Using another `WP_Query` object to create a [nested Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop#Nested_Loops) will probably work.